# What is the idea of | in twig

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-2.1, twig-extension

I have a question, I have this code :

```
{% set texte_article = 'Simple text' %}
{% set url_article   = 'simple/url' %} 
<a href="{{ texte_article|twitter_share_link(url_article) }}" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a>
```

What is the idea of `text_article|twitter_share...`, I don't understand what do `|`. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance
And what is the difference between : `{{ 40|lipsum }}` and `{{ lipsum(40) }}` ?
the filter method is :

```
public static function getShareLink($s_url)
{
    $a_params = array(
        'url' => 'url',
        'hl'  => 'share'
    );

    return self::URL . http_build_query($a_params, '', '&amp;');
}
```

Comment: `{{ 40|lipsum }}` is a `filter` apply to 40 and `{{ lipsum(40) }}` is a `function` with 40 as parameter

Comment: twig documentation... this unknown.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is to apply a Twig fliter. 
I guess you have a `twitter_share_link` function in your project which need `url_article` as parameter

Comment: What is the role of `text_article|` ?

Comment: How to transform this in php ?

Comment: `text_article` is the variable which is applied the `twitter_share_link` filter. you should seach `twitter_share_link` in the code of your project to understand the utility of this filter

Comment: _How to transform this in php ?_ => Look this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: @doydoy44....I edited the question...So the method get one parameter...But I don't understand how is use `text_article`

Comment: Are you sure that `getShareLink()` is the method of the `twitter_share_link` filter? if yes, I d'ont understand either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114957/discussion-between-harea-costicla-and-doydoy44).